# Autoit IniWrite() overwriting key?

Tags: autoit

Autoit IniWrite() overwriting key?

```
    IniWrite(@ScriptDir & "\php\php.ini", "Zend", "zend_extension_ts", '"' & @ScriptDir & '\Files\filename1.dll"')

    IniWrite(@ScriptDir & "\php\php.ini", "Zend", "zend_extension_ts", '"' & @ScriptDir & '\Files\filename2.dll"')

 //line 2 is overwriting the line 1?
```

**It outputs the following within the php.ini:**

> [Zend]
>   zend_extension_ts="C:\Documents and
>   Settings\App\Files\filename2.dll"

**When it should output the following:**

> [Zend]
>   zend_extension_ts="C:\Documents and
>   Settings\App\Files\filename1.dll"
>   zend_extension_ts="C:\Documents and
>   Settings\App\Files\filename2.dll"

Theirfore; how can I achieve the above output - can someone post some example code please, as I can't see anything on this on their documentation page?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure it out! - by using FileWriteLine()

Answer (score 1):

That the key is overwritten actually makes sense. A key name must be unique in an INI file within a section. This is also clearly stated in the help file.